# TextArea control which i can control colors / fonts

Tags: html, user-controls, textarea

I currently have a textarea control on a page. The user will enter text into the control. The content of the control is bespoke code.

I want to (from code) be able to apply formatting (color / bold / italic / font) to different parts of the text- very much like visual studio.

Like visual studio, and any other IDE, i dont want the user to have control over formatting the textarea- most editors i see give a control which the user can change style.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're talking about a WYSIWYG editor for a textarea. You should try using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). These editors use a html attribute called 'contentEditable'. So by setting this attribute to true (e.g. `<p contentEditable="true"></p>`) they can then use the content editable javascript methods to edit it, providing an interface that calls the javascript of course. You can read a little about `contentEditable` and the similar attribute `designMode` [here on WebMonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/2008/07/make_any_content_editable_with_javascript/).